# Open Source Software for Batch converting WAV to BWF for free?

Tags: bwf, wav, batch-processing, file-conversion

Hi,

Does anyone know an open source software package that can batch convert WAV-files to BWF?
I can only find paid and non open source packages (rematacator for example).
The project I'm working is completely open source and there is no budget, at least not yet :)
Since we need to convert 2000 WAV-files, we really need a reliable batch converter.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to add bext chunk while converting the wav file ? Why do you want to convert the wav files ?

Comment: BWF MetaEdit is probably what you need. http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Wave Agent by Sound Devices might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, I actually didn't know it could convert from WAV to BWF! Thanks

Comment: WAV and BWF ? Isn't BWF, Broadcast Wave File then what is simple WAV ?


Comment: BWF is an extension of a WAV file with an added broadcast extension chunk containing more detailed metadata info. 

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at AudioGate from Korg. Been very reliable whenever i've converted things. I'm not sure you'll be able to convert 2000 files at once but it's worth a try.